# What is the best way to define notification endpoint?

Tags: rest, api-design

I’m defining a new schema for a restful api which can get and add notifications. An existing endpoint `notifications` is already used for something else unfortunately, so I have two ideas on what to do instead.

```
/NotificationAPI/1.0.0/notification_endpoints
```

or

```
/NotificationAPI/1.0.0/notification_configurations
```

Which one do you find makes more sense?

Comment: What's the point of versioning your API if you aren't going to use it? Introduce v2 of the `notifications` API that works in the way you feel it should. Existing users can stick with v1 and users who need access to the new functionality reference v2. Or by "something else" do you mean something completely unrelated?

Comment: Hey James. It's an unrelated service as you say at the end of your reply

Comment: in that case the naming of the API is really down to whatever makes sense to you. You'd need to provide more context about what the existing API does and how that differs from the new API you are looking to create.